# Не могу в простую рекурсию

Tags: java, рекурсия

Поясните за 'рекурсию'  не так что б прям сложна, прошу много но, опишите как будет работать, вернее как работает в деталях следующий код, а именно меня интересует одна вещь, я почему то думал что выводить должно с конца списка а выводит в методе main от начала и не могу понять почему.

```
class RecTest {
int[] num;

RecTest(int i) {
    num = new int[i];
}

void printArray(int i) {
    if (i == 0) { return; }
    printArray(i - 1);
    System.out.println("[" + (i - 1) + "]" + num[i - 1]);

}}

public class program {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    RecTest ob = new RecTest(10);

int i;

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {  ob.num[i] = i;  }
ob.printArray(10);

}}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Посмотрите, что будет если рекуррентный вызов заменить телом функции, т.е.:

```
printArray(int i) {
  if (i == 0) { return; }
  printArray(i - 1);  // <- заменяем на тело функции (строки 2-4)
  System.out.println(i - 1);  //для краткости
}
```

Получаем:

```
printArray(int i) {
  if (i == 0) { return; }
    if (i - 1 == 0) { return; }
    printArray(i - 1 - 1); 
    System.out.println(i - 1 - 1);  
  System.out.println(i - 1);  
}
```

Еще раз:

```
printArray(int i) {
  if (i == 0) { return; }
    if (i - 1 == 0) { return; }
      if (i - 1 - 1 == 0) { return; }
      printArray(i - 1 - 1 - 1); 
      System.out.println(i - 1 - 1 - 1); //i-3
    System.out.println(i - 1 - 1);       //i-2 
  System.out.println(i - 1);             //i-1           
}
```

Теперь посмотрите в какой очередности вызывается `println`.

Если поменять местами две строчки

```
printArray(int i) {
  if (i == 0) { return; }
  System.out.println(i - 1); //сначала вывод
  printArray(i - 1);         //потом рекуррентный вызов
}
```

и проделать тоже самое, получим:

```
printArray(int i) {
  if (i == 0) { return; }
  System.out.println(i - 1);              //i-1
    if (i - 1 == 0) { return; }
    System.out.println(i - 1 - 1);        //i-2
      if (i - 1 - 1 - 1 == 0) { return; } 
      System.out.println(i - 1 - 1 - 1);  //i-3
      printArray(i - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1);      //i-4
}
```

Порядок вызова `println` поменялся. Такая рекурсия называется хвостовая. В общем случае получается:

```
recursion(arguments){
   //обязательно ограничение глубины рекурсии 
   //до рекуррентного вызова
   if( is_end(arguments) )return;  

   before(arguments);   //все что до рекуррентного вызова выполняется в прямом порядке

   recursion(change(arguments)); //рекуррентный вызов 

   after(agruments);    //все что после - выполняется в обратном порядке 
}
```

Само собой порядок зависит не только от очередности вызовов, но и от того как вы изменяете аргументы. В вашем случае `i` изменяется от большего к меньшему и рекурсия меняет порядок.

Answer (score 2):

Вам надо просто поменять местами вот эти ваши строки:

> printArray(i - 1);
>   System.out.println("[" + (i - 1) + "]" + num[i - 1]);

В данный момент вы сначала доходите рекурсией до первого элемента без вывода в консоль и после этого движетесь обратно, поочерёдно завершая код в методах, начиная с последнего.
В итоге вы и завершаете код в методе сначала для последнего его вызова и в последнюю очередь для первого.